# Connect war task to cargo deploy task

Tags: gradle

I've create a gradle script in order to deploy a deployable on a container using `cargo` plugin:

```
class RemoteContainer {
    String name
    String container
    String hostname
    Integer port
    String username
    String password
    String purpose
}

def remoteContainers = [new RemoteContainer(
        name: 'wildfly10',
        container: 'wildfly10x',
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 9990,
        username: 'user',
        password: 'passwd',
        purpose: 'development'
    )
]

remoteContainers.each { config ->
    task "deployDev${config.name.capitalize()}"(type: com.bmuschko.gradle.cargo.tasks.remote.CargoDeployRemote) {
        description = "Deploys WAR to remote Web Application Server: '${config.name}'."
        containerId = config.container
        hostname = config.hostname
        port = config.port
        username = config.username
        password = config.password
        dependsOn war
    }

    task "undeployDev${config.name.capitalize()}"(type: com.bmuschko.gradle.cargo.tasks.remote.CargoUndeployRemote) {
        description = "Deploys WAR to remote Web Application Server: '${config.name}'."
        containerId = config.container
        hostname = config.hostname
        port = config.port
        username = config.username
        password = config.password
        dependsOn = war
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, I've created several tasks in order to create custom war files according to its scope:

```
task createQAWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
    archiveName "webapi-demo-${versioning.info.display}.war"
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
    webInf {
       ...
    }
}

task createDevelopmentWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
    archiveName "webapi-dev-${versioning.info.display}.war"
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
    webInf {
       ...
    }
}

task createTestingWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
    archiveName "webapi-test-${versioning.info.display}.war"
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
    webInf {
       ...
    }
}

task createProductionWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
    archiveName "webapi-prod-${versioning.info.display}.war"
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
    webInf {
       ...
    }
}
```

I'd like to link that `deployDev` tasks pick the war artifact generated on `createDevelopmentWar`.

I've tried to set `dependsOn` property to `createDevelopmentWar`:

```
remoteContainers.each { config ->
    task "deployDev${config.name.capitalize()}"(type: com.bmuschko.gradle.cargo.tasks.remote.CargoDeployRemote) {
        description = "Deploys WAR to remote Web Application Server: '${config.name}'."
        containerId = config.container
        hostname = config.hostname
        port = config.port
        username = config.username
        password = config.password
        dependsOn = createDevelopmentWar  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, gradle it's getting me this message:

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating root project 'webapi'.
>     Cannot cast object 'task ':createDevelopmentWar'' with class 'org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War_Decorated' to class 'java.lang.Iterable
>     '

I've also tried setting `dependsOn` to `war` task, nevertheless the message is the same.

**EDIT**

Once, I've changed the syntax for `dependsOn = [createDevelopmentWar]`, I'm facing up with another trouble:

It's getting me this message:

> Execution failed for task ':deployDevWildfly10'.
>   Deployable D:\projects\living\platform\webapi\build\libs\webapi-dev-89c157a-dirty.war does not exist

It's trying to get the artifact from `build\libs\`. Nevertheless, the war artifact has been created in `destinationDir = file("$buildDir/dist")`:

```
task createDevelopmentWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
        archiveName "webapi-dev-${versioning.info.display}.war"
        destinationDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
        webInf {
           ...
        }
    }
```

How could I set cargo picks the artifact up from previously `war type task(createDevelopmentWar)` execution information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dependsOn = createDevelopmentWar` results in a call to `setDependsOn(createDevelopmentWar)` which expects an `Iterable` that a task is not.

`dependsOn createDevelopmentWar` would result in a call to `dependsOn(createDevelopmentWar)` which expects a varargs parameter and thus sould add the task to the dependencies.

If you really want to replace all dependencies with this one dependency, you have to do it like `dependsOn = [createDevelopmentWar]`.

Comment: Thanks @Vampire. I'm getting another message now. It's picking the artifact up from an incorrect folder. I've edited the post. Any ideas?

Comment: Follow the documenation of the plugin you are using. By default it detects deployables automatically from an applied `war` or `ear` task, but in your case this is not applicable and so it doesn't find the file it tries to deploy. Define a deployable with your custom war and you will be fine. If the plugin is developed correctly, and you use file(createDevelopmentWar) as file in the deployable closure, you might even be able to not specify the `dependsOn` explicitly, but it should be done implicitly anyways.

Comment: I'm able to figure out what you mean. Nevertheless, I don't quite to get how to change the script (I'm newbie using gradle). Could you provide me any helping stuff code showing how to get it?

Comment: I mean how do I create a `deployable` inside my `deployDev-like` tasks. Otherwise, how could I avoid using `dependsOn` and create an implicit way to do that?

Comment: As I said, look at the documentation of the plugin you use, in your case https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin/. I cannot help much, as I don't use that plugin. I just had a quick look at the docs and code to anwer your question as good as possible without diving in too deep.